# What is setlocale() for?

Tags: c, locale, setlocale

I'm studying c++ and I have found this function of C++ library:
`setlocale` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/setlocale/) but I'm not able to understand what is it for.

I have used on Ubuntu:

`printf ("Locale is: %s\n", setlocale(LC_ALL,"") );`

it prints `Locale is: en_US.UTF-8`

but on macOs it prints:

`Locale is: C` what does means this C?

In what context and how should it be used?

Comment: it seems to be related to currency, date and other region specific input interpretation

Comment: from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/ The "C" locale is the minimal locale. It is a rather neutral locale which has the same settings across all systems and compilers, and therefore the exact results of a program using this locale are predictable. This is the locale used by default on all C programs

Answer (score 3):

Read on Linux  the [setlocale(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html) and [locale(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html) man pages. Read also the [internationalization and localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) wikipage.

On Debian and Ubuntu, you might run (as root) the `dpkg-reconfigure locales` to add more locales.

Then you could set your `LANG` (and `LC_ALL` and others) environment variables (see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)) to change the language of message.

For example, I have the French UTF-8 locale installed. If I do

```
% env LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 ls /tmp/nonexisting
```

I'm getting the error message in French:

```
ls: impossible d'accéder à '/tmp/nonexisting': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

If I use the `C`  locale (which is the default one), it is in  English:

```
% env LC_ALL=C ls /tmp/nonexisting
ls: cannot access '/tmp/nonexisting': No such file or directory
```

As a rule of thumb, you want to `export LC_ALL=C LANG=C` before running commands that you exhibit on this forum (e.g. because you don't want to show error messages from the compiler or the shell in French).

If you are *coding* a program which you want to internationalize (ez.g. to be easily usable by people understanding only French or Chinese), you need at least to use [gettext(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gettext.3.html) (notably for `printf`  format strings!) and perhaps [textdomain(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/textdomain.3.html) and you'll need to use [msgfmt(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/msgfmt.1.html) for dealing with message catalogs. Of course you'll need to build catalogs of translated messages.

Localization also influences how numbers are parsed and printed (with a comma or a dot separating the thousands or the decimal digits) and how money and time get printed and parsed (e.g. [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html)).

Comment: question: when I try `LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 ls /tmp/nonexisting` i get mixed French and English message: `ls: impossible d'accéder à '/tmp/nonexisting': No such file or directory`. Is there a way I can make everything French like in the answer? My bash version is 5.0.11. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's locale specific settings. For example, in some countries comma is used for decimal separator, in others, it's dot. In the US 22,001 is often understood to be 22 thousand and 1, in some European countries that's 22 point 001.

Dates can be given in DD/MM/YYYYY (most of Europe) or MM/DD/YYYY (in the US) format and so forth.

Comment: In what context and how should it be used?

Comment: When you want your program to execute in a place that uses a different convention..