# decimal format is comma instead of dot

Tags: c

I'm trying to plot using gnuplot and I am no being able to plot values correctly. When I print the values with `printf("%.9f %.9f\n", x, y);` the result I get is this: 499,000000000 -0,725536846. but I am expecting a . instead of ,. I tried using `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "POSIX");` to change the output but it is not working.

can someone tell me how to fix this output ?

Update: I get `Local pt_BR.UTF-8` when I run: `printf("Local %s\n", setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, ""));`

here is a small example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("Local %s\n", setlocale(LC_ALL, ""));
    printf("%.9f\n", 1.255165164684);
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
Local LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=pt_BR.UTF-8;LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8;LC_NAME=pt_BR.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=pt_BR.UTF-8;LC_TELEPHONE=pt_BR.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_BR.UTF-8
1,255165165
```

Comment: From the C standard: *"A value of **"C"** for locale specifies the minimal environment for C translation; a value of **""** for locale specifies the locale-specific native environment. Other implementation-defined strings may be passed as the second argument to setlocale."* In other words, `setlocale` is essentially worthless, because it has no universally defined behavior. Check the return value from `setlocale`. If it returned NULL, it ignored your request.

Comment: In general, I'd also add that you need to provide a [mcve] along with the output of `locale` on your system.

Comment: @user3386109 I told the program to print the locale im in. when I put en_GB as the strin in setlocale I get a NULL just like you said

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt : I added an example, thanks for reminding me

Comment: I believe some IDEs/libraries (?) tweak the environment/options (?) such that a perfectly valid program misbehaves (and I think it was discussed here on SO before, but can't find it). What development tools are you using?

Comment: @pmg I'm using gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0 and geany as a text editor

Comment: [Here is an answer that may be useful to you.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46940175/3386109)

Comment: A stripped down program also prints commas? `#include <stdio.h>` and `int main(void) { printf("%f\n", 3.14159); }` See the output of `gcc -E`, grep "locale" (?), see if you find something strange... add headers back in until the problem reappears?

Comment: @user3386109 thanks that help. All I did was follow the instructions to find which lang was installed and changed my setlocale to : setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8")